# Gitlab CI/CD Integrations Push Events Filter

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Does anyone know if 
Trigger -> Push Events wildcard Filter in Gitlab CI/CD Integrations accepts comma-separated branches or just wildcard?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GitLab 15.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/12/22/gitlab-15-7-released/#webhook-push-events-support-regular-expressions) (December 2022, 3 years later) adds a new option:

> ### Webhook push events support regular expressions
>
> For webhooks triggered on push events, you can now define a [regex pattern](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#filter-push-events-by-branch) that aligns with your branching strategy.
>
> For example, you can use `^(feature|hotfix)/` to allow any push to the `feature` or `hotfix` branch to trigger an event.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_7/webhook_push_events_support_regular_expressions_image.png -- Webhook push events support regular expressions]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#filter-push-events-by-branch) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/369104).

Comment: So, if I wanted the event to fire only for push a specific branch, I would just use something like `^(main)`?

Comment: @liakoyras Yes, or just `^main/`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried both comma separated and space separated values, to no avail:

`feature/* bugfix/* release/* hotfix/*`: it makes gitlab crash (error 500)

`feature/*,bugfix/*,release/*,hotfix/*`: it doesn't work

So I ended up creating four webhooks, each one with a single wildcard.